# How to get Instagram access token programatically using the official Instagram Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, instagram

I would like to use the "[Instagram gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem)" to get my personal Instagram access token programatically so that I will not have to be asked to authenticate at all when viewing my non-public photos.

In other words, I need `access_token` in my code for my application Without any kind of user authentication interface interaction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's customary, and expected, that you'll show the minimal code necessary to demonstrate what you've tried to solve this on your own. What did you try? Why didn't it work? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: By the way the gem's help file says: "The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions or if you need help with your code." - this is a bit of buck-passing by the gem authors who are guessing that most problems will be with code that you can get help with here. They could of worded that in the readme better to avoid any misunderstanding. Please note that Stack Overflow is not in any way an official support channel for the gem.

Comment: Hi there, the closest info i found is from here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/Instagram/OAuth but I still can not making out a code to that will get Instagram access token programmatically given the credential to do so. I am still working on it i will post back if i find leads. Thanks!